# Do Tallboys count as found bodies, and how do I hide them if so?

Tags: dishonored

I encountered Tallboys on Lady Boyle's Last Party, blink-jumped behind them and assassinated them, making the frame drop to the ground.  I could not, however, find any body to hide left amongst the rubble.  Also, as I dropped back down to the ground, I fell on a guardsman, and assassinated him.  His body still remained, so I was very confused by this.

Which leads me to the question, do tallboys count as found bodies, and if so, how do you hide them?

UPDATE: Apparently the body would disappear with Shadow Kill, but then does the wreckage of the tall boy count for chaos if found?

Comment: Do you have the Shadow Kill skill? This would account for the disappearing Tall Boy body.

Comment: Ah... that makes sense, though does the frame lying there increase chaos?  It would seem that the frame is just as good as the body to be discovered.  If you kill without SK is a body laying about to be hidden?

Comment: @AdamP Shouldn't the guard he also killed, also disappear with Shadow Kill?

Comment: @wraith808 I am interested in knowing if NPCs will notice a downed tall boy (just the frame or stilts) without a body (hidden or shadow-killed). Could you add this into the question?

Comment: @galacticninja good question, as I think that's one of the things that so confused me and made me forget SK- the fact that I was able to assassinate the guard on the ground and he remained.

Comment: @galacticninja its possible the guard saw or heard the kill. Then he would not have disappeared because he would have been alerted.

Comment: @AdamP can you assassinate an alerted guard with a drop?  I thought it was similar to assassinations from behind, i.e. the guard had to be unaware.

Comment: @wraith808 if you catch somebody off guard. Say by blinking next to them, blocking their attack, falling on them, etc... You can get an assassination animation even if they were previously alerted to your presence.

Comment: Unless you mean you did an aerial (drop) assassination. In which case I apologize for the confusion and I do not have an explanation.

Comment: @AdamP - yes, it was an aerial (drop) assassination from the tallboy.  He was walking under he tallboy as I blink jumped to the tallboy.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I reckon the tallboy body (not including its frame/stilts/wreckage) will be treated like a normal body, and could be found if not hidden properly.

But the tallboy's frame/stilts/wreckage, based on my test, does NOT count as a 'dead body', even if the enemy found out all about it.

To test, I played [Lady Boyle's Last Party](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/Lady_Boyle%27s_Last_Party), and finished that mission with '0 dead or unconscious bodies found' in the mission stats. I had [Shadow Kill](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/Shadow_Kill), and always killed stealthily so this will ensure that no bodies will be found at all.

I then loaded a savegame made near the mission exit. [After that, I proceeded to kill a nearby tallboy stealthily](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSAOP.jpg), then hid and shot a crossbow bolt at the tallboy's wreckage, alerting a nearby guard to check out the wreckage:
[image]

After I proceeded to finish the mission, the [missions stats still say that there are '0 dead or unconscious bodies found'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZWL6.jpg).

Comment: +1 - I have to say, I love your scientific method to answering questions. Thanks! :)

Comment: @wraith808 I'm curious about the same thing in the question; I might as well test it. =)